# How to pass value through multipart entity method from app to api side?

Tags: android

I want to pass value from app side to api. In this api call to pass image,first name, email, telephone and locality. In debug mode checked values are not passed.

**Below code**

```
 File file = null;
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.addHeader("X-COMPANY", currentcity);
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            if (imagepath != null) {
                file = new File(imagepath);
                entity.addPart("pic", new FileBody(file));
            }
            entity.addPart("firstname", new StringBody(firstName, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entity.addPart("telephone", new StringBody(phonenumber, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entity.addPart("location", new StringBody(locaity, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            Log.d("URL Request: ", url.toString());
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: Above code in MultipartEnity in bodyparts have list size is 4 and Each list have body,header and name. In name field:firstname but no value field. Whats the problem in this code

Comment: Why u use ``httpPost.setEntity(entity);`` couple time ?

Comment: Sorry i removed that

Comment: ``DefaultHttpClient()`` and ``StringBody()`` is deprecated, are you try **Retrofit** instead ?

Comment: What is the another method to do this?

Comment: I think you can use http://square.github.io/retrofit/, it useful and easy to use than ``HttpClient``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107208/discussion-between-saravanan-selvam-and-danh-dc).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not passing header correctly.Use below code-

```
HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(strUrl).openConnection()));
            httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type-", "multipart/form-data");
            httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");

 MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            if (imagepath != null) {
                file = new File(imagepath);
                entity.addPart("pic", new FileBody(file));
            }
            entity.addPart("firstname", new StringBody(firstName, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody(email, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entity.addPart("telephone", new StringBody(phonenumber, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            entity.addPart("location", new StringBody(locaity, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));

            httpcon.addRequestProperty(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());

            httpcon.setUseCaches(false);
            httpcon.setDoInput(true);
            httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpcon.connect();

             OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
                entity.writeTo(httpcon.getOutputStream());
                os.close();
                httpcon.connect();

            int responseCode = httpcon.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == 200)
            {
                InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpcon.getInputStream());
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        inputStream);

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        inputStreamReader);

                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                }

                return stringBuilder.toString();

            }
```

Comment: i want to compulsory to pass the header @sarika

Comment: yeah you have to pass header to post file
 httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type-", "multipart/form-data");
            httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");

Comment: httpcon.setRequestProperty("COMPANY", 0); i passed like this but values are not pass to server side.

Comment: Why you need that header company?

Comment: TRy this httpcon.addRequestProperty("COMPANY", 0);

Comment: httpcon.setRequestProperty("X-COMPANY", 0);

Answer (score 1):

```
 Server Side api Code in C# is below
adminAssignmentDto is a model which include input parameters




 if (httpRequest.Form.AllKeys.Count() > 0)
                {
                    adminAssignmentDto.Id = Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest.Form["Id"]);
                    adminAssignmentDto.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(httpRequest.Form["Date"]);
                    adminAssignmentDto.SchAppId = Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest.Form["SchAppId"]);
                    adminAssignmentDto.TeacherId = Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest.Form["TeacherId"]);
                    adminAssignmentDto.SubjectId = Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest.Form["SubjectId"]);
                    adminAssignmentDto.StandardId = Convert.ToInt32(httpRequest.Form["StandardId"]);
                    adminAssignmentDto.Division = httpRequest.Form["Division"];
                    adminAssignmentDto.Text = httpRequest.Form["Text"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The default HTTP client was deprecated in Lollipop so we have to download http client lib [here](http://tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/).